# How do I view a midi device stream

Tags: streaming, midi

I have a midi controller, and it creates two files on my ubuntu system `/dev/dmmidi` and `/dev/midi1`. I want to see the raw output of my midi device when I push buttons and move sliders. I've tried `tail`ing the file. I've tried `screen`ing into the file. I've tried `less`ing the file. I've tried all of those commands as root. The output is always blank.

When I run `aplaymidi -l` I see my device. How do I get the bytestream from my midi device? I only want to read data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `/dev/*midi*` devices are just for compatibility with the legacy OSS interface; the actual ALSA devices are in `/dev/snd/`.

To show incoming MIDI messages, run `aseqdump -p xxx` with the port name shown by `aseqdump -l`.

To show the raw MIDI bytes, run `amidi --dump -p xxx` with the port name shown by `amidi -l`.